# Differentiability doesn't imply Lipchitz for $f:U\subset\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I've got this question on my mind for a while and I can't find an argument for it. Here goes my question.

Let $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ an open set and $f:U\to\Bbb R$ differentiable at $a\in U$. Exist $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset U$, then for every vector $h\in\Bbb R^n$ with $|h|<r$ follows $a+h\in B(a,r)$. By the differentiability at $a$ we have

$$f(a+h)-f(a)=\langle\nabla f(a),h\rangle+r(h),\quad\lim_{h\to0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0.$$

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0,$ exist $\varepsilon>0$ such $|h|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow|r(h)|<|h|$. Then, for every $|h|<\varepsilon$ we have
$$|f(a+h)-f(a)|=\left|\langle\nabla f(a),h\rangle+r(h)\right|\leq\left|\langle\nabla f(a),h\rangle\right|+|r(h)|\leq|\nabla f(a)||h|+|h|.$$
So we get $M>0$ such that $|f(a+h)-f(a)|\le M|h|$.

But why is it not possible tweak these steps to find $\varepsilon>0$ and $M>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$ for every $x,y\in B(a,\varepsilon)$ ?

Comment: See how you obtained $M$ in your proof, and you will see that it, essentially, depends on $\nabla f$ in the point "around" which you are making your construction (in your case: $a$). That shows what the counterexample for the stronger statement must look like: it must have the differential of the function unlimited near the boundaries of $U$. For a concrete counterexample, take $n=1, f(x)=\sec x, U=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and look what happens near $-\pi/2$ or near $\pi/2$.

Comment: Or take $U = \{ x | x >0 \}$ and $f(x) = {1\over x}$. It is locally Lipschitz, hence Lipschitz on compact subsets of $U$, but not globally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer: There are counterexamples. For example, suppose we take $n=1$ and define $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f'(0)=0.$

But for any $r>0$ you can find a non-zero rational $x\in (-r,r).$ For this $x,$ there is a sequence $y_n$ of irrationals converging to $x.$ For this sequence we have

$$\tag 1 \frac{f(y_n)-f(x)}{y_n-x}=\frac{-x^2}{y_n-x}.$$

This is unbounded as $n\to\infty$ because the numerator just sits there at a nonzero value, while the denominator $\to 0.$ And because $(1)$ is unbounded, we have a counterexample.